# Element-ui v-for can not attach the Array

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

Here is a 'el-option' with the 'v-for'.And I use the Data props ,but there is no correct display.

```
      <el-form label-width="100px">
          <el-row v-for="(row,index) in form.rows">
            <el-col v-for="col in form.cols[index]" :span="6">
              <el-form-item :label='col.SHOWNAME'>
                <el-select v-model='col.value'>
                  <el-option v-for='item in dicts[col.SHOWNAME].value' :key="item.Code" :label="item.Name" :value="item.Name"></el-option>
                </el-select>
              </el-form-item>
            </el-row>
          </el-col>
        </el-form>
```

And there is the Data

```
data:{
  form:{
    cols:[[{....,SHOWNAME:"Rectype"},{....}],[{.....}]],
    rows:[1,1]
  },
  dicts:{
     "Rectype":{name:"xxx",value:[{Code:"43010",Name:"xxxx"},{.....}]}
  }
}
```

I can sure the loop is correct,I can use the Chrome Console to find the 'dicts["Rectype"].value' ,But it never shows in the 'el-select '
with the 'dicts[col.SHOWNAME]'

Is there any one can help me ...tks

Comment: Could you please provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: well,I find the problem.The 'cols' and 'dicts' is added by the ajax data,it's dynamical.And in the js 'for' loop,I add the every 'col' and 'dict' into them.After that all,I use the function to get What dicts include by ajax.Now I change the order,I get all dict,and search by ajax.After that I add the col.

Comment: Sorry to hidden many details :)

Comment: So good you found out the solution. You can also try using computed properties if you have data filled asynchronously